# Listen to changes in specific values of a Map passed in props

Tags: reactjs

My React application doesn't use Formik or other libraries, but simply defines a Map of field values. That Map of Values, along with the setter function, is passed to different components. E.g.

Top-Level Component

```
const [valueMap, setValueMap] = useState(new Map());

const initializeValueMap = () => {
   var valMap = new Map();
   valMap.set('field1', '');
   //...
   valMap.set('street', '');
   valMap.set('city', '');
   valMap.set('state', '');
   valMap.set('zip', '');
   valMap.set('streetMailing', '');
   valMap.set('cityMailing', '');
   valMap.set('stateMailing', '');
   valMap.set('zipMailing', '');
   setValueMap(valMap);
```

Address Component

```
<Address handleValueMapChange={handleValueMapChange} valueMap={valueMap} />
```

There are 2 radio buttons: (1) Mailing Address Same As Main, (2) Mailing Address Different From Main. If the mailing address is different, the `XXXMailing` variables will be individually set. If  the 1st radiobutton is clicked, the Address fields will be copied over into `XXXMailing` from `XXX`.

Now **if the Same radio button is already selected and then the user changes the Main Address fields**, I need to listen for that and automatically propagate to the `XXXMailing` fields as well.

But I can't have an Effect like

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.valueMap.get('sameAsMA') === true) {
        // ... Propagate to Mailing equivalents ...
    }
}, [props.valueMap.street, props.valueMap.city, props.valueMap.state, props.valueMap.zip]);
```

because those aren't available variables, those are values in a Map. The only thing I can do is

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.valueMap.get('sameAsMA') === true) {
        // ... Propagate to Mailing equivalents ...
    }
}, [props.valueMap]); // The whole Map change
```

which would create an infinite loop, because I'd be continuously changing the Map. Any suggestions?

Comment: u should trigger when a user is finish with a input field and then do the checks or just do the checks at the end befor submit the data form

Comment: Hard to provide a thorough answer without what's going on in `//  ... Propogate to Mailing equivalents ...` but look into using `useMemo` to work with a memoized version of your address map. If that doesn't work, you can always make the state more granular (would probably be a good idea anyways) to avoid unnecssary re-renders.

Comment: I think you're making life hard on yourself by putting these in a map (and furthermore by having the same values as state and props, if I'm interpreting your snippets correctly). There seem to only be a finite set of values, just pull them out of the map and use them as individual state.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your logic and rethink a little:

1. make buttons like "use different shipping address"
2. add a state var to check if the mode is active or if your using billing one
3. with onchanged on the button the object will be filled
4. use onfocusout on the billing address, check in the function you call if the different billing is active, if? Then do the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. To avoid an infinite loop, I can restrict the Effect by which map values are different. The Effect will stop applying when they're the same and have been copied over.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.valueMap.get('sameAsMA') === true && 
        (
            props.valueMap.get('street') !== props.valueMap.get('streetMailing') || 
            props.valueMap.get('city') !== props.valueMap.get('cityMailing') || 
            //...
        )
    ) {
        props.handleValueMapChange("streetMailing", props.valueMap.get('street'));
        props.handleValueMapChange("cityMailing", props.valueMap.get('city'));
        //...
      }
}, [props.valueMap]);
```